# Adapt geometry on printed points

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, image-manipulation, imaging

I draw a vectorial geometry with some calibration points around it.

[image: Original draw]

I print this geometry and then I physically scan the printed calibration points (I can't scan the geometry, I can only scan the calibration points).
When I acquire these points, these aren't in their position anymore because of some print error or bad print calibration.

[image: Scanned image]

The question is: 
Is there any algorithm that helps me to adapt the original geometry in base of the new points scanned?
In practice I need to warp the geometry in order to obtain the real geometry printed on the paper with the same print error that I have on the calibration points.

The distortion is given by the physical distortion of the material (not paper but cloth) during the print process. I can't know how much the material will distort during the print.

Comment: There are infinitely many *possible* ways to do what you apparently ask. Do you know any more about the likely kinds of distortion that would come from the printing and scanning processes?

Comment: To elaborate a bit on Rory's comment: The distortion does not seem to be one of the standard models (e.g. radial distortion, perspective transform, etc.) What can you say about the independence of the distortion of each point? It seems as if there is an underlying coarse distortion pattern (might even be representable with a linear transform). Is there some additional (independent) noise on every point? Otherwise, the middle point in the top row looks really out of place. What possible distortion sources are there in your acquisition setup?

Comment: Thank you all.the distorsion is given by the phisical distorsion of the material (not paper but cloth) during the print process. I can't know how much the material will distorce during the print. Having an original matrix of points and a final matrix of points(i can insert in the drawing more than 8 points) i can't in any way calculate the new points of the path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are algorithms to help you with that. In general you need to learn/find the transformation between the two images that you have.

Typical geometrical transformations are affine transformations (shift, scale, rotation, shear, reflections) which need at least three control points or piecewise local linear/ local weighted mean which need at least 4-6 control points. The more control points you have, the better in general.

Given a set of control points in one image and the corresponding set of control points in the other image there are algorithms for finding the optimal transformation between if you specify a class (affine or piecewise local linear). See for example [fitgeotrans](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html) in Matlab. I don't know how exactly it solves the problem by I guess by some kind of optimization. It should be easy to find available implementations for other programming languages (Python, C, Java).

What remains is finding the correspondence between the control points in the two images. For a few images you may be able to do that by hand, but in the general case you might want to automatize this as well. General image registration algorithms like [imregister](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html) should do well for your images. They give you a good initial estimate for the transformation (may already be sufficient) so that then identification of the corresponding point pairs is trivial (always take the nearest) and allow refining.

So I advice you to first just try to register the images (gray scale data) with an identity transformation as starting value. Then identify corresponding point pairs and refine the transformation either using an affine or a piecewiece/local transformation. Then apply the transformation on the geometry to get the printed geometry. Depending on your choice of programming languages you will find many implementations that do the job.